# If a XAML element's Visibility is set to Invisible, does its property bindings continue to be updated?

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, uwp, c#-2.0

For example, if I have a TextBlock that has its Text property bound to some string in my ViewModel, does that binding continue listening for changes to the ViewModel string, if the TextBlock's Visibility is set to Invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does continue listening for changes!

The binding mechanism involves an CLR type (source) and a dependency property (target) defined in a dependency object, and is not constrained by how certain of its properties are currently defined, unless that correlation is explicitly defined.

What makes up the `Binding` process is the fact that we provide the implementation for a `CLR` object to communicate its changes onto an object defined in our *View*, but also the fact that we have our dependency objects properties looking up for this notifications. It's a mechanism which is independent of the `Visibility` of the object which is being targeted.

Otherwise imagine the situation where we were using a boolean property from a certain `ViewModel` to control the `Visibility` of a control in the View. With the latest SKD versions the system handles this automatically for you when using `x:Bind`, but lets imagine you are utilizing the `{Binding }` markup to define your bindings.

What do you have to do? Define a `Converter` to convert the bool value to the `Visibility` enum and the inverse.

- Now imagine that we start by having the `ViewModel` boolean flag set to *false*, which would map to `Collapsed`. What would happen now if you changed your *boolean* property to *true* and propagated that notification to the target control?

Since your control was set to have its `Vibility` to *Collapsed*, it would stop listening to the *boolean* property, and there would be no way of actually having the control `Visibility` set to *Visible*, unless we would force such, even though we had changed the *boolean* flag to true and propagated the notification.

Having your element set as **Collapsed** simply means that there's no space being reserved for it on the layout and therefore it will not be displayed.
But what composes the element underneath can and will still be updated as many times as it is requested.

Comment: Explained perfectly well. Thanks.